# Angular 7, getting "Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null" only in production

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular 7 application.  I trap and log all errors in Angular.  I keep seeing these in PROD, but never a single time have they happened in my DEV or TEST system.  I've spent hours trying to recreate this error, but I can never recreate it in DEV.

I understand what it's telling me, basically, I'm trying to build out DOM elements before the parent is created.  My question, is based on the stack trace, how do I figure out which DOM element is the problem?  I've studied my code, and I cannot figure out what is causing this issue.  Or is there something I can trap, to get enough information, to actually figure out what the real problem is.  Basically, I just don't have enough information to figure this out, and I don't know where to go.

The fix is simple, when I figure out which element is the problem, I'll just wrap it with an *ngIf to make sure the parent is loaded before the append is done.  But I cannot find any element that seems like it should need this.

```
Stack: TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
at create_dom_structure (eval at  (https://www.example.com/scripts.49e4e250152772542da5.js:10828:1), :1:16231)
at load_map (eval at  (https://www.example.com/scripts.49e4e250152772542da5.js:10828:1), :1:101028)
at Object.load (eval at  (https://www.example.com/scripts.49e4e250152772542da5.js:10828:1), :1:107834)
at HTMLDocument. (https://www.example.com/1.b3bc70e4e5a6b31d07a9.js:2744:22)
at l (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:29375)
at c (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:29677)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (https://www.example.com/polyfills.3264be9933cdaa844d60.js:10589:31)
at Object.onInvokeTask (https://www.example.com/main.4b64a4bdce04500a9d5d.js:50991:33)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (https://www.example.com/polyfills.3264be9933cdaa844d60.js:10588:60)
at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (https://www.example.com/polyfills.3264be9933cdaa844d60.js:10361:47)
```

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace as sometimes the culprit class/template is buried quite deep. Also, have you tried deploying a non-prod build and replicate the error ?

Comment: did you check that parent of child is exist ? EX: this.renderer.appendChild(parentElement, childElemnt)

Comment: You can try using prod environment in local with sourcemap, it would help.

Comment: "ashisd.gd" that should be the full stack trace, at least, that's all I'm getting.  I dump error.stack.  Is there a way to get more stacktrace?
"worstCoder" I agree, that's exactly the problem.  My question is, based on the stack trace, how do I figure out what the parent is?  I don't do an 'AppendChild' anywhere in my code, but I'm using TypeScript, so TypeScript will be doing it under the covers.  I have no idea how to tie this back to TypeScript code so I can figure out where the issue is.
"htm", that's actually a really good idea.   I never thought of that.  I'll work on that tomrorow.